# How to push a docker image to public dockerhub repository from a private github repo's codespace?

Tags: docker, github, docker-registry, codespaces

If I do the following:

```
docker pull hello-world
docker login registry-1.docker.io
docker tag 9c7a54a9a43c rabonagol/hello-world:test
docker push rabonagol/hello-world:test
```

where upon being prompted the password after line 2, I enter my docker hub password, then the push doesn't work.  It returns:

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/rabonagol/hello-world]
01bb4fce3eb1: Preparing 
unauthorized: access token has insufficient scopes
```

I have also tried, instead of line 2: `docker login`.  This didn't work either, even though with both ways of login, it says "logged in successfully".  e.g.

```
@qAp ➜ /workspaces $ docker login registry-1.docker.io
Username: rabonagol
Password: 
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/codespace/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Is there some configuration I need to set for the Codespace, or is this action simply not allowed?

Comment: Please show that you have logged in with the same username. If you don't wish to disclose that username, create a username that you can show in a [mcve].

Comment: The login command should be `docker login -u rabonagol`. You don't need to specify a registry for Docker Hub.